# Setting up linked libraries on Linux

Tags: c++, ubuntu, libraries

Developing on linux is new for me, and I'm having trouble setting up the environment. I have a relatively small program which relies on the following libs:

```
-lboost_date_time -lboost_regex -lmysqlclient -lmysqlcppconn -lexpat
```

I'm using eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. What do I need to do with the package manager, and inside eclipse to successfully compile? I was told to use `sudo apt-get libboost*`, but that prints a whole army of conflicts and then comes to the saddening conclusion:

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I believe I installed `libmysqlcppconn-dev`, and `libexpat1-dev` correctly.
The only thing I've done in eclipse, is added the -l stuff to the linkers library settings.

So in conclusion, the OS and the IDE are both new to me, I would appreciate detailed help.

Dump from the terminal below:

```
libboost-dev is already the newest version.
libboost-iostreams1.46.1 is already the newest version.
libboost-iostreams1.46.1 set to manually installed.
libboost-serialization1.46.1 is already the newest version.
libboost-serialization1.46.1 set to manually installed.
libboost1.46-dev is already the newest version.
libboost1.46-dev set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost-date-time1.48-dev : Conflicts: libboost-date-time1.46-dev but 1.46.1-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libboost-filesystem1.48-dev : Conflicts: libboost-filesystem1.46-dev but 1.46.1-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libboost-graph-parallel1.48-dev : Conflicts: libboost-graph-parallel1.46-dev but 1.46.1-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libboost-graph1.48-dev : Conflicts: libboost-graph1.46-dev but 1.46.1-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libboost-iostreams1.48-dev : Conflicts: libboost-iostreams1.46-dev but 1.46.1-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libboost-math1.48-dev : Conflicts: libboost-math1.46-dev but 1.46.1-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libboost-mpi-python1.48-dev : Conflicts: libboost-mpi-python1.46-dev but 1.46.1-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libboost-mpi-python1.48.0 : Conflicts: libboost-mpi-python1.46.1 but 1.46.1-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libboost-mpi1.48-dev : Conflicts: libboost-mpi1.46-dev but 1.46.1-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libboost-program-options1.48-dev : Conflicts: libboost-program-options1.46-dev but 1.46.1-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libboost-python1.46-dev : Depends: python-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-python1.48-dev : Depends: python-dev but it is not going to be installed
                           Conflicts: libboost-python1.46-dev but 1.46.1-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libboost-regex1.48-dev : Conflicts: libboost-regex1.46-dev but 1.46.1-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libboost-serialization1.48-dev : Conflicts: libboost-serialization1.46-dev but 1.46.1-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libboost-signals1.48-dev : Conflicts: libboost-signals1.46-dev but 1.46.1-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libboost-system1.48-dev : Conflicts: libboost-system1.46-dev but 1.46.1-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libboost-test1.48-dev : Conflicts: libboost-test1.46-dev but 1.46.1-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libboost-thread1.48-dev : Conflicts: libboost-thread1.46-dev but 1.46.1-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libboost-wave1.48-dev : Conflicts: libboost-wave1.46-dev but 1.46.1-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libboost1.48-dbg : Conflicts: libboost1.46-dbg but 1.46.1-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libboost1.48-dev : Conflicts: libboost1.46-dev but 1.46.1-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libboost1.48-doc : Conflicts: libboost1.46-doc but 1.46.1-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: We would appreciate a detailed question; I think you need to add your errors from `apt-get`.

Comment: Please post the conflict message you get. Usually you can use `sudo apt-get -f install` to fix your problems.

Comment: that's really more a package install issue than anything else: `apt-get` is telling you you have held packages, did you install third party packages (eclipse maybe)? Is this a fresh install or an upgrade from a previous version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @didierc A fresh install. I installed eclipse also with `apt-get`

Comment: Have you upgraded all packages recently?

Comment: @alexchamberlain I believe I used the ubuntu update manager to install updates right after the OS was booted for the first time.

Comment: I'm not a Ubuntu user, but it looks like you already have a version of libboost.

Comment: @alexchamberlain Maybe it's something in eclipse? What I wrote are all the things I done, because I think the whole idea in linux is that `apt-get` sets up things in the `/usr/include` folder, so I don't need to do anything more, but I'm just guessing. The only thing I've done in eclipse, is added the -l stuff to the linkers library settings.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 has libboost.46.xxx included in distribution but from messages provided ("libboost-wave1.48-dev : Conflicts:...") seems that you unsuccessfully tried to upgrade the package and now have conflicts with dependencies. The solution would be to remove and then reinstall boost libraries. As i didn't do it on Ubuntu, i would propose to ask this question on Ubuntu forums -http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community/web-forums.

Comment: btw, did you try to compile your app before trying to install the boost packages, maybe what you already have is enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`libboost-dev` is a virtual package pointing to the latest boost development package set deployed in the repository. At the moment, for your version of ubuntu, it seems like 1.48.02 is the latest (see the [package description](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libboost-dev)). There may be other versions available in the repositories, as for instance 1.46, which seems to be the one which was available at 12.04 release time.

When launching :

```
apt-get install liboost*
```

the package manager will try to install every package whose name starts with `libboost`, not just the latest version. What you really want is to install only one set of dev packages (and all the runtime ones you may need for your apps, but this will be taken care of by the dependency tracker of `apt`).

the following command:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install libboost-dev
```

or

```
aptitude install libboost-dev
```

should upgrade your system to the latest version available of the boost dev package.

Comment: you may also try askubuntu.com which is also part of the stackexchange network, or the ubuntu forums.